# Is it possible to create a reliable php regex to get search query string from a Google url?

Tags: php, regex

A possible url from Google may look like:

```
https://www.google.co.in/search?q=user%27s+search+query&oq=user%27s+search+query&gs_l=serp.3...
```

so the regex will produce: "user's search query".

Comment: Maybe http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php?

Comment: I'd say the answer is "Yes, it is possible".

Comment: why a regex? it's a url. there's functions to parse urls down into their basic components. don't use a chaingun when a scalpel will do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get the query string, then parse the vars into an array.  It should be `q` currently for Google search terms:

```
parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $result);

echo $result['q'];
```

The query string will be:

> q=user%27s+search+query&oq=user%27s+search+query&gs_l=serp.3

And the `$result['q']` will be:

> user's search query

And the full `$result`:

```
Array
(
    [q] => user's search query
    [oq] => user's search query
    [gs_l] => serp.3
)
```